# Intel 3165 not working on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, 19.10, iwlwifi

I have a laptop with the dreaded Intel 3165 card in, and I have just installed latest stable ubuntu (19.10) and its using kernel (5.3.0).

There is no wifi and searching wifi options yields nothing, here is what `dmesg` gives me:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
    [5.584060] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 Refused to change power state, currently in D3
    [5.584337] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
    [5.593346] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -5
```

I have tried doing the whole copy of 7265 ucode files to various permutations but nothing works, I have however seen one post where someone says their card seems to work out the box on ubuntu 19.10 but struggles to connect to certain access points.

Right now I am not sure what to try next, as im fairly new to linux and while there are lots of these fixes for the drivers I worry a bit that its saying there are PCI issues, so not sure if I need to do anything in bios.

Any help would be great!

Comment: So I have got it working HUZZAH! but im still a bit confused as to why it all blew up. So in my BIOS there was some D3Cold settings which were enabled, I disabled them and suddenly it all started working when I booted up.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1848953

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours banging my head against the wall with network manager in one hand and rfkill in the other. Finally I switched off my D3 cooling in the BIOS/UEFI settings as suggested in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204683/intel-3165-not-working-on-ubuntu-19-10/1256167#comment2020941_1204683):

> So I have got it working HUZZAH! but im still a bit confused as to why it all blew up. So in my BIOS there was some D3Cold settings which were enabled, I disabled them and suddenly it all started working when I booted up.

...and BAM! Everything worked straight away with my Intel 3165. Saved my day!