# Intel Wireless 3165 doesn't work

Tags: wireless, 20.04, intel

I have a problem with my wifi in Ubuntu. It works well in W10 but in Ubuntu there is no a visible adapter. I tried different versions of Ubuntu, now I'm with `20.04`.

`uname -a`

`Linux F6-Plus 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

When I execute `lspci` in terminal there are no information about the network controller.

After that I execute:

`echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

If I execute `lspci` after that, shows information about the network controler

`02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)`

Still Wi-Fi doesn't work but it seems the controller is there. If I restart and execute `lspci` there's no information about the network controller again.

I'm very lost I don't know what to do to solve that.

Thanks

Edit1 to add more information

`sudo dmesg modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl`

Nothing.

After doing `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

```
sudo dmesg modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl
[  159.974862] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  159.975268] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[  159.998862] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

```
dmesg | grep 02:00
[    4.545917] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: i2c-GDIX1002:00 supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.545940] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: i2c-GDIX1002:00 supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.548360] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: i2c test failed attempt 1: -121
[    4.573798] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: i2c test failed attempt 2: -121
[    4.601624] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: I2C communication failure: -121
[    4.601749] Goodix-TS: probe of i2c-GDIX1002:00 failed with error -121
[  159.971421] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:3165] type 00 class 0x028000
[  159.971817] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00001fff 64bit]
[  159.972300] pci 0000:02:00.0: Upstream bridge's Max Payload Size set to 128 (was 256, max 256)
[  159.972318] pci 0000:02:00.0: Max Payload Size set to 128 (was 128, max 128)
[  159.973158] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[  159.974677] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x80100000-0x80101fff 64bit]
[  159.974862] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  159.975268] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[  159.998862] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Wireless card is solded to the board, it is not external pci adapter.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: I have tried doing that but no difference. Still no adapter when I turn on. @chili555

Comment: Please clarify. Please turn *OFF* fast boot within Windows 10 and reboot. Next edit your question to show us: `sudo dmesg modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Edited to add your proposal. And yes I turned OFF fast boot in W10. Thank you for your welcome @chili555

Comment: Please excuse my mis-step. I should have said: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl` Please try again. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the information

Comment: "PCI Issues?" Let's check: `dmesg | grep 02:00`

Comment: Edited with more information

Comment: Is this a possibility? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204683/intel-3165-not-working-on-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: I have read that but I don't know how I have to change in the BIOS, I don't understand very well. I don't see nothing about wifi...

Comment: urge them: https://www.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=2634193580176608&id=1573222279607082

Comment: Just the same issue @poige. I haven't tried the first one, but I also have the other two problems. I turn off automatical rotation for the screen after rotate to see well, but the wifi issue... no solution. Just buying a external USB adapter, but you will lose one USB in your laptop.
Hope someone could do something to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made my adapter work on my Teclast F6 plus.

The key is to update BIOS settings.
Here is a configuration that works for me :

### BIOS

- make sure D3Cold is enabled (default configuration is fine)
- chipset > PCI Express configuration > PCI Express Root Port **2** (this is the one used by the card)

  - Hot plug: `enabled`
  - Transmitter Half Swing: `enabled`
  - Extra Bus Reserved: 7

[image]

### Force PCI rescan

As the OP says, the card is not listed unless a pci rescan is forced.

I set up a small systemd service to enable at start

**/opt/pci/rescan.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo 1 | tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
lspci | grep 02:00.0
```

**/etc/systemd/system/pci-rescan.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=PCI rescan

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/pci/rescan.sh
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```bsh
# setup and enable as root
chmod a+x /opt/pci/rescan.sh
systemctl enable pci-rescan
systemctl start pci-rescan
```

The interface now appears and I can use it (named `wls1` on my Arch system).
Using nmcli for instance:

```bsh
nmcli d wifi connect <SSID> password <password> ifname wls1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now my adapter also works! After lots of months...