# WiFi randomly? disconnects until reboot on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, lubuntu, network-manager

Recently I have come across a bug where my WiFi disconnects, and I am unable to find a network until I reboot my computer. I run Lubuntu only and didn't start having this issue for several months of use. I have not had the opportunity to test if this same issue exists over a wired connection.

The only temporary fix I have found to this problem is to reboot my computer, but even then, it only starts working again around 75% of the time. When the WiFi is working, it typically lasts around 0-15 minutes before disconnecting. I've noticed that when I leave the computer on but don't open Chrome/Firefox it tends to last longer before crashing.

When I get disconnected I get a notification such as this on my taskbar.
`10/23/21 10:59 AM - NetworkManager(nm-tray): Connection Lost`

I've only been able to trace the issue to my Network Controller becoming **Unclaimed** and my computer failing to recognize my wireless device, **phy0**. But obviously it's not that simple.

This is seen when comparing `sudo lshw -C network` and `rfkill list` before and after the WiFi disconnects.

### `sudo lshw -C network` before crash

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
   logical name: wlp63s0
   version: 78
   serial: ac:ed:5c:d9:2a:06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-38-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode ip=10.10.79.178 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:135 memory:8a200000-8a201fff
```

### `sudo lshw -C network` after crash

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
   version: 78
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:8a200000-8a201fff
```

### `rfkill list` before crash

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

### `rfkill list` after crash

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

## What I've tried

I have tried too many random solutions to keep track of, but here are some recent ones I feel confident in describing:

1. Reinstalled a fresh copy of Lubuntu 21.10. Problem persisted before making any changes to the system.
2. Reinstalled a fresh copy of Lubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Problem persisted before making any changes to the system.
3. Disabling wifi power management as seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077559/1494827). I didn't notice any improvements so I reverted this change.
4. Removing and reinserting wifi module with `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`
5. Stopping/disabling/starting/enabling `NetworkManager.service` and `network-manager.service`

---

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service

sudo systemctl stop network-manager.service
sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service
sudo systemctl start network-manager.service
sudo systemctl enable network-manager.service
```

---

If this is a driver issue that will be solved by uninstalling/installing different drivers, I'm worried I will break something and I won't be able to connect at all. The fact that I even get a few minutes of connection has kept me hopeful.

## Some extra, hopefully relevant information

### `lspci -k`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 620                                                                                                                                                    
        Kernel driver in use: i915                                                                                                                                                           
        Kernel modules: i915                                                                                                                                                                 
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/                                                                                                                     E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)                                                                                                                                 
        Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Proces                                                                                                                     sor Thermal Subsystem                                                                                                                                                                        
        Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
        Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
        Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
        Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801
3f:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
40:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 600P Series (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation SSD 600P Series
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
        Kernel modules: nvme
```

### `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

### `uname -sr`

```
Linux 5.11.0-38-generic
```

---

Thank you so much for any help/insights. I'll do my best to be responsive and supply any requested info/etc.

## Requested command outputs

### `inxi -n` before crash

```
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp63s0 state: up mac: ac:ed:5c:d9:2a:06
```

### `inxi -n` after crash

```
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: N/A
```

### `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` before crash

```
[    5.140125] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.140130] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.140744] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.184742] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    5.193588] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.194155] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    5.250297] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: base HW address: ac:ed:5c:d9:2a:06
[    5.325343] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.340260] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0 wlp63s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.861219] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.994119] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    6.061098] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

### `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` after crash

```
[    6.141845] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  162.126250] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[  162.126266] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 1 write_ptr 2
[  162.143880] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 549 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2013 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1ab/0x1e0 [iwlwifi]
[  162.143896] Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq nls_iso8859_1 mei_hdcp iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 intel_rapl_msr iwlwifi snd_seq_device snd_timer input_leds uvcvideo x86_pkg_temp_thermal hid_sensor_als intel_powerclamp videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops coretemp hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_v4l2 rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf intel_cstate snd wmi_bmof serio_raw videobuf2_common intel_wmi_thunderbolt hid_sensor_iio_common efi_pstore btusb btrtl cfg80211 industrialio btbcm
[  162.143987] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1ab/0x1e0 [iwlwifi]
[  162.144014]  iwl_write_prph_delay+0x41/0xb0 [iwlwifi]
[  162.144023]  iwl_force_nmi+0x59/0x60 [iwlwifi]
[  162.144030]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x1f8/0x270 [iwlwifi]
[  162.144040]  iwl_pcie_send_hcmd_sync+0x2f0/0x390 [iwlwifi]
[  162.144051]  iwl_trans_pcie_send_hcmd+0x34/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[  162.144060]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x55/0xc0 [iwlwifi]
[  162.144071]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x1f/0x40 [iwlmvm]
[  162.144081]  iwl_mvm_request_statistics+0x72/0xd0 [iwlmvm]
[  162.144090]  iwl_mvm_mac_sta_statistics+0x17d/0x3c0 [iwlmvm]

[  162.144277] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers

[  162.162022] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 549 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/../iwl-trans.h:1342 iwl_mvm_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4f7/0x550 [iwlmvm]
[  162.162118] RIP: 0010:iwl_mvm_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4f7/0x550 [iwlmvm]
[  162.162142]  iwl_mvm_dump_nic_error_log+0x28/0x130 [iwlmvm]
[  162.162150]  iwl_mvm_nic_error+0x35/0x40 [iwlmvm]
[  162.162158]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0xbf/0x270 [iwlwifi]
[  162.162170]  iwl_pcie_send_hcmd_sync+0x2f0/0x390 [iwlwifi]
[  162.162182]  iwl_trans_pcie_send_hcmd+0x34/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[  162.162191]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x55/0xc0 [iwlwifi]
[  162.162201]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x1f/0x40 [iwlmvm]
[  162.162209]  iwl_mvm_request_statistics+0x72/0xd0 [iwlmvm]
[  162.162217]  iwl_mvm_mac_sta_statistics+0x17d/0x3c0 [iwlmvm]

[  162.162394] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[  162.220661] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[  164.833034] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  164.937153] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[  164.937159] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[  164.937161] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  164.937163] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
[  164.937174] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.

[  164.971939] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 39 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/../iwl-trans.h:1342 iwl_mvm_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4f7/0x550 [iwlmvm]
[  164.972072] RIP: 0010:iwl_mvm_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4f7/0x550 [iwlmvm]
[  164.972099]  iwl_mvm_dump_nic_error_log+0x28/0x130 [iwlmvm]
[  164.972108]  iwl_mvm_nic_error+0x35/0x40 [iwlmvm]
[  164.972116]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0xbf/0x270 [iwlwifi]
[  164.972128]  ? iwl_fw_dbg_collect_desc+0xde/0x190 [iwlwifi]
[  164.972140]  iwl_fw_dbg_error_collect+0x59/0xc0 [iwlwifi]
[  164.972151]  iwl_mvm_up+0xf0/0xca0 [iwlmvm]
[  164.972185]  __iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x2b/0x180 [iwlmvm]
[  164.972193]  iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x2a/0x40 [iwlmvm]

[  165.030282] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe!

[  167.142128] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  167.142251] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[  167.142318] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:3f:00.0 failed with error -5
```

### `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` after crash

```
Oct 24 14:24:39 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099879.8878] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Oct 24 14:24:39 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1635099879.8880] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist

Oct 24 14:24:39 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099879.8920] device (wlp63s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Oct 24 14:24:39 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099879.8927] manager: (wlp63s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Oct 24 14:24:39 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099879.8964] device (wlp63s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 24 14:24:40 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1635099880.1283] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate

Oct 24 14:24:40 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099880.2347] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp63s0 created
Oct 24 14:24:40 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099880.2353] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp63s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Oct 24 14:24:40 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099880.2362] device (p2p-dev-wlp63s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 24 14:24:40 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099880.2381] device (p2p-dev-wlp63s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 24 14:24:40 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099880.2389] device (wlp63s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 24 14:24:40 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1635099880.2437] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Oct 24 14:24:43 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099883.6603] policy: auto-activating connection 'Bard-secure' (836a0586-f3f8-4fea-8951-9373634d6567)
Oct 24 14:24:43 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099883.6608] device (wlp63s0): Activation: starting connection 'Bard-secure' (836a0586-f3f8-4fea-8951-9373634d6567)
Oct 24 14:24:43 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635099883.6610] device (wlp63s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1635100574.8515] sup-iface[0x55611c431120,wlp63s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635100574.8534] device (wlp63s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635100574.8851] dhcp4 (wlp63s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635100574.8852] dhcp4 (wlp63s0): state changed bound -> done
Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635100574.8948] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635100574.9042] device (p2p-dev-wlp63s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1635100574.9068] radio killswitch /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:3f:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill3 disappeared
Oct 24 14:36:14 sanguine NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1635100574.9071] dns-sd-resolved[4cf74bac7d90a488]: send-updates failed to update systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 2 not known
```

Comment: Very well documented. What does `inxi -n`say? It will tell, which driver you're using

Comment: We already know the driver in use: "Kernel modules: iwlwifi" After a disconnect, please show us: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @kanehekili Thank you. From my understanding my Intel 8265 / 8275 wireless adapter is unable to find the iwlwifi Linux kernel driver. I've updated my post with command outputs.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks! I've updated my post with outputs from before and after.

Comment: @waltinator Yes, will do! I'll do my best to understand them but for now I've updated my post with the output for anyone who would like to look along.

Comment: Do not post whole log files! 99+% of the log entries are not of interest. Use an editor (on  a copy of the file), and keep ONLY the error entries, plus 2 lines before and 2 lines after. You should end up with a max of 50 lines, and probably fewer than 50. Edit your question to add information,  and use the formatting tools. Comments are for US to ask YOU to improve your Question, to help us help you.

Comment: @waltinator I appreciate you helping me learn to ask better questions. I did my best to remove irrelevant information from my pastebin files and formatted them in my original post instead. Please let me know if you think I removed too much or should reduce further.

Comment: Please note in your dmesg: "HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?" Then see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266523/intel-wireless-3165-doesnt-work And, more likely, in my opinion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368323/wifi-icon-disappear-no-internet-iwlwifi-errors

Comment: @chili555 Thank you so much for your input. Hardware issue sounds most likely as I only suddenly started having this issue. I will re-insert the card and get back to you. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

As a newcomer to Ubuntu Linux, I followed the various clever folks reset Wifi driver code/command solutions to my random drop-out of Wifi problem on Ubuntu 20.04. However, I have also found it was a hardware problem with the Wifi adapter card connection, just like @sanguine had.  With Windows 10 Wifi drop-out wasn't a problem I was aware of. In changing the OS to Ubuntu, the problem manifested itself as a random but regular occurrence, especially in the days leading up to 1/11/2021. As per the @chili555's advice I followed the instructions for my HP Envy Laptop and removed and reinserted the Wifi adapter card and rebooted Ubuntu. You can see that now on Nov 4th I haven't yet had to reboot to restore Wifi for more than 72 hours. So be aware that many hours can be spent tracking through software solutions when a relatively quick hardware operation might solve the problem. I will now see how it goes from here with bated breath after each sleep/suspend event. I have learnt more about the functioning of Ubuntu during this process, so thanks to all that have contributed their software solutions.

```
|david@david-HP-ENVY|-Notebook:~$| last | grep reboot|
|:----|:-----------:|:--------------:|:---------------:|------:|
|reboot system boot:|5.11.0-38-generi|Mon Nov  1 12:48|still running| 
|reboot system boot|5.11.0-38-generi| Sun Oct 31 22:13 |- 23:48  (01:34)|
|reboot system boot|5.11.0-38-generi|Sun Oct 31 16:03| - 22:13  (06:09)|
|reboot system boot|5.11.0-38-generi|Sat Oct 30 20:40| - 16:03  (20:22)|
|reboot system boot|5.11.0-38-generi|Fri Oct 29 20:43| - 20:40  (23:56)|
|reboot system boot|5.11.0-38-generi|Thu Oct 28 22:28| - 20:42  (22:14)|
david@david-HP-ENVY-Notebook:~$
```

After the above, I did experience one further Wifi drop-out, but that may have been caused by my dual boot system with Windows 10 doing an unexpected Win 10 update automatically, and then the grub booting into Ubuntu on the Win 10 update restart - systems being betwixt and between causing some temporary instability I believe.

However, this prompted me to look again at the Wifi drop out issue again, and I also found a link on how to disable the power-saving function on the Wifi Adapter. It seems that the power saving function could cause conflicts on restart from sleep/suspend. I used this instruction provided by @Jeremy31 [on the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878097/more-wifi-issues-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-ath10k-pci) to disable power saving during sleep / suspend - It changes (3) enabled to (2) disabled

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reverse the (2) and (3) instructions above to re-enable the power-saving mode.

Since doing the above change, I have not experienced the WIFI dropping out randomly. Long may that situation continue!

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced wifi dropout on a new Lenovo w/ Intel Wifi 6.  I tried upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 then 21.10 and also the wifi.powersave = 2 config change with no success.  It looks like power management is the issue as changing Settings-Power-PowerMode to Performance has solved the issue, at least for me