# Wifi randomly disconnects, No visible networks until reboot 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager

My wifi randomly disconnects & doesn't reconnect, I tried turning it off and then on again but that makes it worse and the network names are even no longer visible.

I've tried all the solutions on every similar question I could find

[Wifi networks are not showing in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769521/wifi-networks-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04)
[WiFi randomly? disconnects until reboot on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371173/wifi-randomly-disconnects-until-reboot-on-ubuntu-20-04)
[WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd`
`sudo service NetworkManager restart`

but absolutely nothing seems to work & I'm beyond frustrated,
is there any way to hard rest the wifi without having to restart my computer?

I had a similar problem with my bluetooth so I used this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403817/i-cant-turn-on-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts) by AndreGraveler in the comments
So is there any similar solution for wifi?

Comment: I am in your exact same boat! All previous solutions (power save mode, kernel bug, etc.) does not work for me. I noticed it usually occurs on low battery and yes I have power save mode on 2. Very frustrating to have to restart for wifi card to work! If you found a solution, please answer your own post. Given so few still face this issue in 2023, I think this may be a hardware issue with my 5+ year old Acer laptop running behind the times and with older Nvidia versions.

Comment: @Parfait Trust me dude I'm still looking for a solution, the situation has gotten so bad I have to connect my laptop to my mobile & turn on USB tethering just to connect to the internet since I can't restart my laptop 5 times every time I want WiFi, so if I do find a solution I'll definitely post it here otherwise I'll probably throw this laptop in the dumpster ( btw let me know if you come across a fix)

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer in this forum. Please bear with me if I'm not doing anything correctly.

I had a similar problem and was able to do a bit of debugging and figure out that the problem was with the driver. I will outline the steps to reset the driver below. And hope it works for you.

1. Install hwinfo if you don't already have it
   `sudo apt-get install hwinfo`
2. Find the driver name `sudo hwinfo --network | grep Driver`
3. In case if you get multiple results pick the one which looks like the wifi driver. (Ex: `iwlwifi`)
4. Look for any other deps on this driver `sudo lsmod | grep iwlwifi`. You should see something like the following. Which would mean `iwlmvm` uses the driver.

```
iwlwifi               446464  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              970752  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

5. Use the following commands to remove and and add the modules (order is probably important as well)

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlmvm
```

After this you should start seeing the networks again.

6. For long term use. Create a shell script with all the commands used in the step 5. And every time you run into this issue you can just run the script

Comment: Unfortunately for step 1. you'll need an internet connection. So consider having it installed beforehand.