# Filing a bug for wifi adapter not found for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, bug-reporting, iwlwifi

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 freshly on my machine yesterday, the WiFi adapter has not been working since then.

I tried [various](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/feaj5z/fix_for_intel_3186_iwlwifi_bug_in_ubuntu_1910_or/) [methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204683/intel-3165-not-working-on-ubuntu-19-10) and found many users faced the same issue and like them, I couldn't solve it.

I even added [this ppa](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1886247) and still the same result.

So I figured I want to file a bug as mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en). When I entered `ubuntu-bug wifi`, the result displayed this ss below:

[image: bug-report]

How can I install the package that is mentioned above?

EDIT 1: Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-generic                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: ff
   serial: 40:b0:34:09:e5:48
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full latency=255 link=yes maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:126 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff


*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 6a:1f:3d:89:fa:e7
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[   10.208965] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[   10.288841] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[   10.288974] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[   10.290197] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
[   23.806043] Modules linked in: cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_generic kvm ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel uvcvideo crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_intel_dspcfg videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common snd_hda_codec aesni_intel videodev btusb snd_hda_core mc mei_hdcp btrtl btbcm btintel intel_rapl_msr crypto_simd cryptd snd_hwdep bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc glue_helper i915 iwlwifi snd_pcm rapl intel_cstate intel_xhci_usb_role_switch hp_accel hp_wmi joydev input_leds serio_raw snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event lis3lv02d cfg80211 snd_rawmidi sparse_keymap roles snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer drm_kms_helper snd mei_me mei input_polldev acpi_pad soundcore mac_hid processor_thermal_device i2c_algo_bit intel_rapl_common intel_wmi_thunderbolt hp_wireless fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect wmi_bmof int340x_thermal_zone sysimgblt
```

Comment: You linked to a bug report which reports "Fix Released".  You didn't mention which Ubuntu install media you used (*thus I can't check whether or not your install included this fix*), but you'll note the bug report was filed on the kernel itself (ie. `linux`) and not 'wifi'.  I'd first look at which media you used to install your system?  Was it 20.04.1 media?

Comment: @guiverc yes, it's the 20.04.1 media. And the bug was reported on Lenovo Thinkpad, I'm using HP laptop; so there are some mismatch.

Comment: The brand of laptop means nothing... I assumed given you linked that bug report that your wifi chipset was 'rtw88' (realtek) as that is what the PPA was for (regardless of brand of laptop).  You didn't provide any details as to what research you did (`sudo lshw -C network` to list hardware of class network etc) so we make assumptions; I assumed you worked out that was for your hardware & thus why you used that PPA.

Comment: I've edited and added some useful information I tried before. Hope that helps! @guiverc

Comment: If you told us what WiFi adapter you have, someone might offer advice.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think the output of `sudo lshw -C network` mentions about my WiFi adapter. Do let me know if it's not the case.

Comment: I just see your Realtek Ethernet Card there. Nothing about and Intel WiFi card which would appear in its own section. What is the model number of your ThinkPad?