# Intel Wireless 3165 doesn't work on Teclast F6 Plus laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I have a problem with my WiFi in Ubuntu. It worked well in Windows 10 but I wiped the drive to do a clean Ubuntu installation and there is no visible adapter.

I'm with 20.04, haven't tried others, laptop model is Teclast F6 Plus.

```
uname -a

Linux zor 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I execute `lspci` in terminal there are no information about the network controller.

After that I execute:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

If I execute `lspci` after that, then it shows information about the network controller

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
```

Still WiFi doesn't work but it seems the controller is there. If I restart and execute `lspci` there's no information about the network controller again.

After doing `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

```
sudo dmesg modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl
[  696.049457] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  696.049746] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[  696.080295] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5

$ dmesg | grep 02:00
[    4.978555] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.978580] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.978878] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: i2c test failed attempt 1: -121
[    5.006608] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: ID 9111, version: 8030
[    5.012235] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/i2c_designware.4/i2c-5/i2c-GDIX1002:00/input/input10
[  695.996420] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:3165] type 00 class 0x028000
[  695.996788] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00001fff 64bit]
[  695.997189] pci 0000:02:00.0: Upstream bridge's Max Payload Size set to 128 (was 256, max 256)
[  695.997255] pci 0000:02:00.0: Max Payload Size set to 128 (was 128, max 128)
[  695.998085] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[  696.031838] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x80100000-0x80101fff 64bit]
[  696.049457] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  696.049746] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[  696.080295] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Wireless card is soldered to the board, it is not an external PCI adapter.

I'm very lost, I don't know what to do to solve that.

Disabling D3 didn't help:
[Intel 3165 not working on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204683/intel-3165-not-working-on-ubuntu-19-10/1256167#comment2020941_1204683)

Comment: Please check UEFI ("BIOS"). It mat have a settings that is disabling the WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution will help you: [Intel Wireless 3165 doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266523/intel-wireless-3165-doesnt-work/1326290#1326290)
If not: I had a similar problem with my Teclast f7 plus laptop. I had to change two things in the BIOS (assuming the default):

1. Advanced --> RC ACPI Settings --> Native PCIE ENABLE --> **Disabled**
2. Chipset --> South Cluster Configuration --> PCI Express Configuration --> PCI Express Root Port 2 --> Hot Plug --> **Enable**

https://kepkuldes.com/image/JYyaXB
https://kepkuldes.com/image/JYyIee